# How do I change PyCharm output so it shows all yahoo finance data when using company.history()?

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I am using yahoo finance in python and when I run the following code:

```
print(apple.history('max'))
```

It gives me this output:

```
                  Open        High  ...  Dividends  Stock Splits
Date                                ...                         
1980-12-12    0.100323    0.100759  ...        0.0           0.0
1980-12-15    0.095525    0.095525  ...        0.0           0.0
```

How do I get the output to show the Low price, Close price, and Volume for each date as many sites show it does? It only shows me the 3 dots in between High and Dividends.

Comment: What's `apple`?

Comment: sorry apple is the variable I used to yahoo_finance.Ticker('AAPL')

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`ticker.history()` returns a Pandas [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). You can access any column using the column name e. g. `'Low'`. A primer on indexing and selecting data can be found in the [docs.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)

By default the number of rows, that are shown of a DataFrame are limited. However, you can disable this limit.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

apple = yf.Ticker('AAPL')

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(apple.history('max')[['Low', 'Close', 'Volume']])
    # or: display(...) if working with jupyter
```